How to have custom marker symbol('[' and ']') in Plotly.js
I'm working on a project that requires graphs. I'm using Plotly with JS.
I want custom symbols '[' or ']' as markers on the graph.
Although i prefer without usage of svg, I'm open to change.
How?
I tried:
HTML Code:
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Graphs</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="graph-1"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

JS Code:
index.js
graph_1_data = [{
    x: [1, 2, 3],
    y: [1, 2, 3],
    mode: 'lines+markers',
    line: {
        shape: 'linear',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    marker: { 
        symbol: "[", #Here even though I give '[' it's showing circle[it's default probably] on the plotted graph
        size: 15
    }
}]
graph_1_layout = {
    title: "Graph-1"
}
Plotly.newPlot('graph-1',graph_1_data, graph_1_layout); 

Please help me get Custom Markers('[' and ']' to be specific) in Plotly JS

You can not add it as a marker, you can add one of the following: https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/scatter/#scatter-marker-symbol

Disclaimer - I am not a Plotly.js user. The suggested solution was made using an example given on the Plotly forums.
You would need to replace lines+markers with lines+text, and then use the text property of the Plotly graph object to specify individual markers for each of the coordinates.
For example:


var graph_1_data = [{
    x: [1, 2, 3],
    y: [1, 2, 3],
    mode: 'lines+text',
    text: ['[','[','['],
    line: {
        shape: 'linear',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    textfont: {
      size: 25,
      color: 'blue'
    }
}]
graph_1_layout = {
    title: "Graph-1"
}
Plotly.newPlot('graph-1',graph_1_data, graph_1_layout); 
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph-1"></div>



Or, to avoid manually populating your text array with [:
const xCoords = [1,2,3];
const yCoords = [1,2,3];
const markers = new Array(xCoords.length).fill('[');

var graph_1_data = [{
    x: xCoords,
    y: yCoords,
    mode: 'lines+text',
    text: markers,
// ... the rest of the code
}]


Perfect. Thank You. Changing it to line+text worked like a Charm.

@BennyLazarusKamal Glad I could help. There's one thing that might bother you later on - the tooltip. Hover over any of the markers, to see what I mean. There are various ways of handling this (from what I've seen), but the two that you could do is: 1) hide the tooltip altogether, 2) adjust the tooltip so that it displays only the Y value. Let me know if you need any of these, and I'll edit the answer
